# Search & Replace multiple occurence of pattern in a string after enclosing it between [ and ]

Tags: r

Trying to search and replace multiple occurrence of patterns like `"AxB"` or `"AxxB"` in a long string (where `"x"` could be any word character) after enclosing the pattern in the string with a `"["` prefix and `"]"`like for example, `"[AxB]"` or `"[AxxB]"` as also shown in the example below.

Any word character as well as any number of word characters could occur between **A** and **B**. I am only able to locate the pattern but do not know how to replace it by adding a prefix and suffix to the pattern using `gsub()` and possibly `paste()` function. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Converting the following string:

from
`"CCBCACBAHGABGGARBJDFDFADFDFBFDFD"`  to
 `"CCBC[ACB]AHG[AB]GG[ARB]JDFDF[ADFDFB]FDFD"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gsub` to match an `A` followed by the least number of other characters which are not `A` until we reach `B`.  Replace the match with the match surrounded by square brackets.  Below, `x` is the input string (as in the question and repeated in the Note at the end) but it could have been a character vector of such strings, e.g. `c(x, x)`, and it should still work.  No packages are used.

```
gsub("(A[^A]*?B)", "[\\1]", x)
## [1] "CCBC[ACB]AHG[AB]GG[ARB]JDFDF[ADFDFB]FDFD"
```

**Note:**

```
x <- "CCBCACBAHGABGGARBJDFDFADFDFBFDFD"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
txt <- "CCBCACBAHGABGGARBJDFDFADFDFBFDFD"
expected <- "CCBC[ACB]AHG[AB]GG[ARB]JDFDF[ADFDFB]FDFD"

# Find matches.
matches <- regmatches(txt, gregexpr("(?=A).*?(?<=B)", txt, perl=TRUE))[[1]]
matches <- matches[matches != ""]

# Iterate through and make replacements.
for(match in matches){
  txt <- gsub(match, paste0("\\[", match, "\\]"), txt)
}

txt == expected # TRUE
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do the `gsub` part.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `stringr` package (something similar could be done using `gsub`:

```
library(stringr)
string <- "CCBCACBAHGABGGARBJDFDFADFDFBFDFD"
str_replace_all(string, pattern = "(A.*?B)", "[\\1]")
```

Comment: This produces `CCBC[ACB][AHGAB]GG[ARB]JDFDF[ADFDFB]FDFD` which is   not the expected output.